# Java: GET Json from App A and POST it to app B

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

In Java/Spring what is the easiest way to read data from a REST webservice (App A) and post exactly the same data to a different web-service (App B).

I guess you can read the entire response from A into a String using Spring Resttemplate and then create a new requests for posting to B. Any more elegant solution?

Thanks.

Comment: what does your *more elegant solution* mean? RestTemplate is a proper way

Comment: you can also use jersey client's webresource. you can call get or post methods too. http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restful-java-client-with-jersey-client/

Answer (score 0):

When A client reads data, you can use [AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) with a web socket between Spring and B Client. During this time you can let B Client listen to Spring.

Comment: I guess this won't work for me, since App B expects a POST request with the JSON payload. If I could write App B from scratch, this sounds like a suitable option.